# Alternative to using excessive for() loops to search for matches in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

([You can view the full code on codepen here](http://codepen.io/Codewoofy/pen/mVzMZj))

I'm working on a physics simulation project using HTML5 Canvas.
Currently my code uses a lot of for() loops, Drawing a grid, Drawing each particle, checking for collisions ect.
This essentially works, But will cause an FPS drop after 150+ particles have been added to the canvas, Each particle having to loop though the 150 long array and check for collisions.

Each particle in the array is stored in a dictionary like this:

```
{
    x : 10,
    y : 15,
    color : "#FFF"
}
```

The simple collision detection loops through each particle in the array and checks if the y value is equal to the current particle position + 1.

```js
// Begin loop
for (var part in particles) {
   // p = current particle being drawn & Updated to the canvas
   if (p.y + grid.size == particles[part].y && p.x == particles[part].x) {
      move.down = false;
   }
}
// move the particle if allowed
if (move.down) {
   p.y += grid.size;
}
```

This is what the particles array looks like after being populated with 10 particles.

```
[{"x":195,"y":505,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":195,"y":500,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":195,"y":495,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":195,"y":490,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":195,"y":485,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":135,"y":505,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":245,"y":505,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":160,"y":505,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":435,"y":505,"color":"skyblue"},{"x":355,"y":505,"color":"skyblue"}]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? An alternative to using a for() loop?

[You can view the full code on codepen here](http://codepen.io/Codewoofy/pen/mVzMZj)

```js
var fps_last;
var fps = 0;

var grid = {
   size: 5,
   height: 500,
   width: 500,
   padding: 5,
   color: "rgba(100,100,100,0.3);"
};

var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
var canvas_width = canvas.width = grid.width + (grid.padding * 2) + 1;
var canvas_height = canvas.height = grid.height + (grid.padding * 2) + 1;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var particles = [];
var mouse = {};

function draw() {
   animationFrame();
   $(".fps").html(fps + " FPS");
   $(".part").html("Particles: " + particles.length);
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
  // Loop
   for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.width; x += grid.size) {
      ctx.moveTo(0.5 + x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(0.5 + x, canvas.height);
   }
  // Loop
   for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.height; x += grid.size) {
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0.5 + x);
      ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 0.5 + x);
   }
   ctx.strokeStyle = grid.color;
   ctx.stroke();
   // Loop
   for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      var p = particles[i];
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
      ctx.rect(p.x+1, p.y+1, grid.size-1, grid.size-1);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
      var move = {
         down : true
      }
      // Another loop.
      for(var part in particles){
         if(p.y+grid.size == particles[part].y && p.x == particles[part].x){
            move.down = false;
         }
      }
      
      if(move.down && p.y < grid.height+grid.padding){
         p.y += grid.size;
      }
      
   }
}

function particle() {
   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 0;
   this.color = "#FFF";
}

function create_particle(x, y) {
   var npart = new particle();
  // more loops
   for (var i; i < particles.length; i++) {
      if (x == particles[i].x && y == particles[i].y) {
         return;
      }
   }
   npart.x = x * grid.size;
   npart.y = y * grid.size;
   npart.color = "skyblue";
   particles.push(npart);
}

function animationFrame() {
  if(!fps_last) {
     fps_last = Date.now();
     fps = 0;
     return;
  }
  delta = (Date.now() - fps_last)/1000;
  fps_last = Date.now();
  var d = Math.floor(1/delta);
  d > 200 ? fps = 200 : fps = d;
} 

canvas.onclick = function(e) {
   var c = $("#canvas");
   var x = Math.floor((e.x - c.offset().left) / 5);
   var y = Math.floor((e.y - c.offset().top) / 5);
   create_particle(x, y);
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
   if (mouse.down) {
      var c = $("#canvas");
      var x = Math.floor((e.x - c.offset().left) / 5);
      var y = Math.floor((e.y - c.offset().top) / 5);
      create_particle(x, y);
   }
}

$(document).mousedown(function() {
   mouse.down = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
   mouse.down = false;
});

setInterval(draw, 1);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px|Titillium+Web:400,300,600,700|Raleway:400,300,500,600,700|PT+Sans:400,400italic,700);
html,
body {
  background: #111;
  color: #CCC;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#project_container {
  font-family: 'Raleway', serif;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#project_container h2 {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#project_container p a {
  color: white;
}

#project_container p a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

#project_container p {
  color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#projectbox {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

body,
html {
   cursor: default;
}

#canvas {
   outline: solid 1px #FFF;
   display: block;
   margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="project_container">
   <h2>Canvas Testing</h2>
   <p>Testing using the HTML5 Canvas</p>
   <div id="projectbox">
      <!-- Start project HTML -->
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
      <button onclick='particles=[];'>Delete all particles</button>
      <p class='fps'></p>
      <p class='part'></p>
      
      <!-- End Project HTML -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/ this might be of interest if you are willing to use jquery. i'm not sure about the efficiency, but I guess it's easier to read than for loops at least.

Comment: Ill take a look into it, Thanks @tedcurrent

Comment: If you're going to go bigger with this, you would probably manage to get the app running at a constant framerate and not get slower with infinite particles, if you get clever about knowing what particles are settled and at the bottom, and only loop through the last n particles or something.

Comment: I'm planning on reworking the way particle information is stored so that I won't need to use a loop at all, as suggested in another answer, a multidimensional array would work well. And yes, I'm going to be adding a few more things. Some of my other pens show what I've experimented on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about represent the particles in a matrix (2D array) instead of a list.
This way you will be able to check the immediate neighbours in O(1)

Comment: That's a good idea that slipped my tired mind, Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Nice idea ... I would go with you idea of an array representing every cell's "filled | notFilled" status to test if a particle can be moved into an adjacent cell.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize your code you can use [break statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) inside your loop and also use classical for-loop:

```
for (var i, length = particles.length; i < length; i++) {
   if (p.y + grid.size == particles[i].y && p.x == particles[i].x) {
      move.down = false;
      break;
   }
}
if (move.down) {
   p.y += grid.size;
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about break; This has made a big difference. Using @yoram's idea of a 2D Array would further improve performance, Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You may think about another structure with [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
move.down = particles.every(function (particle) {
    return p.y + grid.size !== particle.y || p.x !== particle.x;
});
```

or if you like it better with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
move.down = !particles.some(function (particle) {
    return p.y + grid.size == particle.y && p.x == particle.x;
});
```

Comment: The `.every` method used to be much slower than looping ( `while`, `for` ) ... Has this changed?

Comment: This made a slight improvement, But the frame rate eventually started dropping after around 1000 particles. madox2's answer seemed to make the biggest difference, And using yoram's idea of a 2D Array would further increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

*A few more improvements related to styling and drawing technique:*

**Faster empty grid drawing**

Create the "empty" grid only once at the beginning of the app and save it to an in-memory canvas.

Then `ctx.drawImage(inMemoryCanvas,0,0)` to draw the empty grid on the visible canvas.

`drawImage` is much faster than `fillRect`-ing each cell.

*Example code: reuse an existing grid*

```
// create an "empty" grid on an in-memory canvas
var emptyGrid=drawEmptyGrid();

function drawEmptyGrid(){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=canvas_width;
    c.height=canvas_height;
    cctx.fillStyle='gray';
    cctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.width; x += grid.size) {
      cctx.moveTo(0.5 + x, 0);
      cctx.lineTo(0.5 + x, canvas.height);
    }
    for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.height; x += grid.size) {
      cctx.moveTo(0, 0.5 + x);
      cctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 0.5 + x);
    }
    cctx.strokeStyle = grid.color;
    cctx.stroke();
    return(c);
}

// drawImage the empty grid instead of fillRect-ing each cell
function draw() {
   $(".part").html("Particles: " + particles.length);
   // redraw the entire empty grid from the saved in-memory canvas
   ctx.drawImage(emptyGrid,0,0);
   ...
```

**More efficient styling:**

Repeatedly resetting `context.fillStyle` inside a loop is inefficient. Instead, set the particle color once before the loop.

*Example code: set fillStyle only once before the for-loop*

```
// Particles
ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
```

**More efficient particle drawing**

You can draw all your particle-rects at one time rather than doing `.beginpath, .rect and .fill` for every particle.

*Example code: draw every particle at once instead of drawing each individually*

```
// Particles
ctx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
ctx.beginPath();
for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
   var p = particles[i];
   ctx.rect(p.x+1, p.y+1, grid.size-1, grid.size-1);
   ...
}
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: The reason the fill style is being set for each particle is because I plan to use more than one color for a particle, Some even changing color. That's a good idea with the grid, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option: use a named dictionary using `x` as the key for an array of particles with that `x` value and varying `y` values:

```
particle_object = { x:1, y:2, color:"green"};
if ( !particles[particle_object.x] ) {
     particles[x] = [];
}
particles[x].push(particle_object);
```

and then to look for collisions, just loop through the array in particles[particle_object.x] to check for a collision (and, as mentioned in another answer, `break`ing once you find one.